# How to navigate programmatically with Ionic 4

Tags: routes, ionic4, stenciljs

I have been searching for this for hours, the docs are no help and all the examples I find online are angular related.

I am not using angular or any other framework.  I built my app using the ionic pwa toolkit.

https://ionicframework.com/pwa/toolkit

I have a button, when the user clicks the button I want to navigate them to a new route.  The route is generated dynamically so I cannot set "href" on the button for reasons.

I would like to know how I can do this programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `push` method of the `ion-router` component:

```
document.querySelector('ion-router').componentOnReady().then(router => {
    router.push('/some-url');
});
```

Docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/router#methods